# What is the best way to left align and right align two div tags?

Tags: html, alignment

What is the best way to right align and left align two div tags on a web page horizontally next to each other? I would like an elegant solution to do this if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to align two inline span elements to left and right without float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951530/what-is-the-best-way-to-align-two-inline-span-elements-to-left-and-right-without)

Comment: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41951734/569302) useful

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
<div style="float: left;">Left Div</div>
<div style="float: right;">Right Div</div>
```

Answer (score 35):

As an alternative way to floating:

```
<style>
    .wrapper{position:relative;}
    .right,.left{width:50%; position:absolute;}
    .right{right:0;}
    .left{left:0;}
</style>
...
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Considering that there's no necessity to position the .left div as absolute (depending on your direction, this could be the .right one) due to that would be in the desired position in natural flow of html code.

Comment: this solution works also with IE7 (the accepted answer not: the right div will be floated right but also 1 break down)

Comment: If you have a div below the wrapper div, it will take the place of the wrapper div, an undesirable effect.

Answer (score 8):

```
<style>
#div1, #div2 {
   float: left; /* or right */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with few lines of **CSS** code. You can align **all div's which you want to appear next to each other to right**.

```
<div class="div_r">First Element</div>
<div class="div_r">Second Element</div>

<style>
.div_r{
float:right;
color:red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

use padding tags the above float tags didnt worked out, I used

```
padding left:5px; 



padding left :30px
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the below. The genre element will start where the DJ element ends,

```
<div>
<div style="width:50%; float:left">DJ</div>
<div>genre</div>
</div>
```

pardon the inline css.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has left aligned text and button on the far right.

If anyone is looking for a material design answer:

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="start start">
 <div layout="row" style="width:100%">
    <div flex="grow">Left Aligned text</div>
    <md-button aria-label="help" ng-click="showHelpDialog()">
      <md-icon md-svg-icon="help"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
 </div>
</div>
```