# align images to right in a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

i have something like:

```
<div id="read_more_right">
    <a href="1"><img src='1'></a>
    <a href="1"><img src='1'></a>
    <a href="1"><img src='1'></a>
</div>
```

i want to align all those images to the right in a div

I use this

```
#read_more_right div
{
  align: right;
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I allign this to the right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's *text-align: right;* instead of only *align*

Comment: lol why is the command `text-align` even tho it is a picture?

Comment: Because images are inline-elements (they have `display` set to `inline` by default) and are thereby laid-out together with the text.

Comment: and how should a new user should know that an image elements and text are not different in html? It is very confusing

Comment: By reading the HTML Standard, which is developed by the [World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)](https://www.w3.org/) and the [Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group](https://whatwg.org/) (except for some advanced HTML5 topics both are similar). Please direct your remarks to them.

Answer (score 8):

You could use:

```
#read_more_right a{
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pE47J/

Comment: GREAT! This was the only solution that worked for my site!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to select your div based on ID you need to declare it in the following fashion:

div#read_more_right { text-align: right; }

Answer (score 1):

Try `text-align: right;` -- you may need to set an explicit width on the div in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure, but I think your syntax is wrong. Try this; it worked for me:

```
div#read_more_right 
{ 
text-align: right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `text-align: right;`

I know its not text.. but that's the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

See also: [What is the best way to left align and right align two div tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727958/what-is-the-best-way-to-left-align-and-right-align-two-div-tags) for some answers to a similar problem and [this](http://www.ironspider.ca/adv/cssproperties/floatalign.htm) for a good overview of float and alignment properties.