# Problems right-aligning an image in a div

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, text-align

I'm working on a frontend project. I'm building this widget thing. I've got the majority of the layout completed. I'm having trouble right-aligning an image inside of a div. I have tried `text-align: right`, but it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried the bootstrap class `text-right`, which also did nothing. The specific image here is the right-facing arrow on the right hand side of the widget (the one inside the div with class `zg-collapsedSmallMobileRightArrowCol`. What am I doing wrong here?

The basic part of the code in question here is:

```css
.zg-collapsedSmallMobileRightArrowCol {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.zg-centerVertically {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col zg-collapsedSmallMobileRightArrowCol zg-centerVertically">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RHSuTQw.png" onclick="advanceReview(1)">
</div>
```

`.col` in this case is the bootstrap4 class of the same name.

Although there is a small code-sample above, the entire code-set is available at the following JSFiddle. You will likely need the entire set of code to figure out what the issue is.

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/meawr0tn/1/

Comment: PS: You cant align an image with `text-align`. Its not a text element. You can align it by using `float` or changing it to a block level element with: `display: block;`

Comment: Thanks, I added the basic CSS, but i have a feeling the entire JSFiddle is required for truly coming to an answer. Regarding text-align, according to this stackoverflow, you can use text-align on an image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745232/align-images-to-right-in-a-div

Comment: yes if certain coditions apply, the image can be aligned to the right with text-align. However it needs a container with a higher width then the image itself.

Comment: Ok. In this case the image is inside a container. Specifically `zg-collapsedSmallMobileRightArrowCol`. There is no hardcoded width specified for this container. When rendered in the jsfiddle, you can see there is ample space to the right of the image. So are you saying that if i specify a hardcoded width of the parent container to a size greater than the image width, that it will work with `text-align: right`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex;` is preventing the use of `text-align: right;`. You can use `justify-content: flex-end;` to align that arrow to the right. add: `.zg-centerVertically:last-child { justify-content: flex-end; }` to manipulate only the last flex item which would work then in your fiddle.

```css
.zg-collapsedSmallMobileRightArrowCol {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.zg-centerVertically {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* aligns the picture of your last flex item to the right sides */
.zg-centerVertically:last-child {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* adds a margin to the right side of the picture of the last flex item */
.zg-centerVertically img:last-child {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col zg-collapsedSmallMobileRightArrowCol zg-centerVertically">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RHSuTQw.png" onclick="advanceReview(1)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This works. The only reason this answer was accepted over the other one, is it explained the reason why `text-align: right` wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: I tested it with your fiddle. to only influence the last element and not the first element aswell, you have to use the `last-child` selector:
`.zg-centerVertically:last-child { justify-content: flex-end; }`

Comment: Also, a followup question. If I want 15px padding on the right of the arrow, does that work in conjunction with the `justify-content: flex-end` CSS?

Comment: yes, simply add a margin to the right side of the image. I edited the code to fulfill that requirement aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Use `justify-content:flex-end`

```css
.zg-collapsedSmallMobileRightArrowCol {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.zg-centerVertically {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="col zg-collapsedSmallMobileRightArrowCol zg-centerVertically">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RHSuTQw.png" onclick="advanceReview(1)">
</div>
```