# What is the best way to align two inline span elements to left and right without float?

Tags: html, css

```css
.recentactivitycontent span{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="recentactivitycontent" >
    <span class="myh4 grey pull-left"><img src="images/exampleuser.png" alt="user"/> Admin added one new member.</span>    
    <span class="myh4 pull-right"><img src="images/clock.png" alt="clock"/> 3 min ago</span>    
</div>
```

As you can see, here is a parent div with two span elements inside. When using the `float` property, the problem is that they will not remain vertically aligned.

I want to use something like the `text-align` property to exactly align inline elements. Setting `height` equal to `line-height` with `display:inline-block` is possible, but then I have to set height property every time which I don't want.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this css through flexbox

```
.recentactivitycontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.recentactivitycontent .pull-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox

Your container needs `display: flex; align-items: center;`

Then your children span needs to align themselves using `margin-left: auto` (this will be aligned to right)

Or `margin-right: auto` - this will be aligned to left

Answer (score 0):

Like Ryans Answer this one:

```
.left, .right{
  position: absolute
}

.left:{
  left: 0
}

.right{
  right: 0
}
```

But you have to consider, to put them in a parent with the `position` of `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute`.

Absolute positioned elements in a parent with mentioned positions can be moved around with the parent in case you want them on a specific position on your page whereas absolute positioned elements in a container without specifig position attribute will always overlay the other elements and have a position relative to your browser window.

Comment: I don't think using position absolute or fixed is better way just to align the elements to far ends. Using position absolute element doesn't affect/change the height and width of its parent element. It is like it fixes one thing but breaks the other.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you asked a way using `text-align`, there is a propery [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last#Browser_compatibility) which does align the elements to far end when its value is `justify`.

```css
.main{
  text-align-last: justify;
}

.child{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child">hello</div>
  <div class="child">hey</div>
</div>
```

But, it doesn't have much browser support yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these css to align the images as well as the whole content to move wherever you want.

The position:absolute makes your content to be in a fixed position so that you can easily move the inner div as your wish.

```
.myh4{
    position:absolute;
}
.pull-left{
    left:0;
}
.pull-right{
    right:0;
}
```