# How to align the text with the fa-classes to the right smoothly?

Tags: html

```css
#header .head-social {
  background-color: #7DC651;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37.48px;
}

#header .head-social h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.social-links {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="header">
  <div class="head-social">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>I am a pretty website website, 12345</h3>
      <div class="social-links">
        <div class="facebook"><a href="www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="twitter"><a href="www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="youtube"><a href="www.youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="instagram"><a href="www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="google"><a href="www.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text h3 and the fa-classes doesn't seem to align to the right of the div head-social. They are always on the left side of the div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to left align and right align two div tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727958/what-is-the-best-way-to-left-align-and-right-align-two-div-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```css
#header .head-social{
  background-color: #7DC651; 
  width:100%; 
  height: 37.48px;
}
#header .head-social h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
.social-links {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
#header .head-social { 
  text-align:right; 
} //added this line
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="header">
  <div class="head-social">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>I am a pretty website website, 12345</h3>
      <div class="social-links">
        <div class="facebook"><a href="www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="twitter"><a href="www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="youtube"><a href="www.youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="instagram"><a href="www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="google"><a href="www.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow small block of code huh, why i didnt think of that *smirk* thankss

Answer (score 0):

use `float` instead of `text-align`

set `container to float:right in css`

i hope it helpful for you

```css
#header .head-social {
  background-color: #7DC651;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37.48px;
}

#header .head-social h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  display: inline-block;
}

.social-links {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.container {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="header">
  <div class="head-social">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>I am a pretty website website, 12345</h3>
      <div class="social-links">
        <div class="facebook"><a href="www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="twitter"><a href="www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="youtube"><a href="www.youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="instagram"><a href="www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="google"><a href="www.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with it :
1. With align right :

```
<div id="header">
        <div class="head-social">
            <div class="container" align="right>
                <h3>I am a pretty website website, 12345</h3>
                <div class="social-links">
                    <div class="facebook"><a href="www.facebook.com" ><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="twitter"><a href="www.twitter.com" ><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="youtube"><a href="www.youtube.com" ><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="instagram"><a href="www.instagram.com" ><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="google"><a href="www.google.com" ><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2. With float right :

   .container { float:right; }